# How to add a table of contents with page numbers to a RTF

Tags: java, itext, rtf, tableofcontents

I have sucessfully generated the table of contents but how to add respective page numbers. I am using the [RtfWriter2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrtf/) of iText to create documents.

I have tried below code to add table of contents but no luck.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document doc = new Document();
        RtfWriter2 writer2 = RtfWriter2.getInstance(doc, baos);
        try {
        writer2.setAutogenerateTOCEntries(true);
        Table headerTable = new Table(3);
        headerTable.addCell("Test Cell 1");
        headerTable.addCell("Test Cell 2");
        headerTable.addCell("Test Cell 3");
        HeaderFooter header = new RtfHeaderFooter(headerTable);
        RtfHeaderFooterGroup footer = new RtfHeaderFooterGroup();
        doc.open();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(new RtfTableOfContents("UPDATE ME!"));
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("", new RtfFont("Staccato222 BT"));
        p.add(new Chunk("Hello! "));
        p.add(new Chunk("How do you do?"));
        doc.add(p);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        doc.add(p);

        Chunk c = new Chunk("");
        c.setNewPage();
        doc.add(c);

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            doc.add(new Paragraph( "Dummy line to get multi-page document. Line " + (i + 1)));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        doc.close();
        return baos;
```

Below is the output I am trying for:

**Table of contents**

```
History 1
Intro  2
```

Comment: (1) Did you check https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.lowagie.text.rtf.RtfWriter2 ? There are several TOC examples. (2) The RTF functionality of iText has been abandoned and is not supported anymore. You better use a different library for RTF. Unfortunatly there is no good one available. You may try https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/rtflib.html ? Do a reasearch yourself...

Comment: @Lonzak Yes I have seen those examples but user need to open the document and click on update to show up *table of contents with page numbers*.

Comment: Yes this is how it is done. A real solution is much more difficult and I think not supported by the library...

Comment: @Lonzak is any way to show up the table of contents by default and when ever user click on update only update the respective page numbers.